How to get wall's lengths of rooms with CAD in which I have only the rooms' areas, walls' rough sketch and wall's thickness information

I have a rectangle with known width and length.
I know that there are 4 "rooms" inside such rectangle.
I know how these rooms' walls are distributed inside such rectangle.
I know the area of each room.
I know the thickness of each wall.

Is there any way in any CAD software where I can input these data and the software solve the walls' lengths to match the area conditions?
I mean, the software needs to adjust the walls' lengths to match the areas based on the initial wall rough sketch that I have inputed.

If you post a basic diagram of your rooms and the information I could probably give you a formula that you could calculate dimensions from. You have probably four unknowns and five equations.

Suppose your building is 30.5ft wide by 40.5ft long. A single wall across the width separates rooms A and B from rooms C and D. Walls are 6in thick. A is 300sf, B is 400sf, C is 400sf and D is 100 sf.
It only takes a few minutes algebra to figure out:
$A=\frac{90}{7}*\frac{70}{3}$  ,  $B=(30-\frac{90}{7})*\frac{70}{3}\ , C=(40-\frac{70}{3})*24\ , D=(40-\frac{70}{3})*6$

You can let Excel Solver search good dimensions for the rooms. You draw nothing to Excel, but create 2 expressions - one for the width of the outer rectangle and one for the height of the outer rectangle.
The expressions are built of known data and guessed approximate room dimensions. At least one dimension of each room should contain the known room area. No need to assume the rooms are rectangles, but it's up to you to build the right expressions. This is the way how you tell the details you know.
Let the known exact outer rectangle width be Wr and let the calculated outer rectangle width be We.
Let the known exact outer rectangle height be Hr and let the calculated outer rectangle height be He.
Let Excel Solver vary the guessed room dimensions to make (We-Wr)^2+(He-Hr)^2 to zero.
If a solution exists Excel very likely finds it. Nothing guarantees it's the only possible solution. Excel stops and blinks "ready" as soon as it thinks a solution is found.You can set the tolerance how close zero the sum of the squares of the errors must be.
Your idea of having a possibility to define constraints in a CAD program also as numerical relations is not at all bad. The opposite: such possibility would be extremely useful. Unfortunately I know only elementary CAD programs, so I cannot say if such functionality is already available. In elementary programs the constraints are  geometric or state only very simple relations between dimensions like "keep these items tangential", "keep these items as long", "keep these elements equally spaced" etc... but I have still not seen a possibility to declare "find dimensions which minimize or maximize this or that calculated expression".
